# Bind field to temporary recordset field programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to display a recordset that is created programmatically. But I'm having problems binding the controlsource to the recordset fields.

The following code outputs "#Error" in the FirstField textbox.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rs.Fields
        .Append "A", adInteger
        .Append "B", adInteger
        .Append "C", adInteger
    End With

    rs.Open

    With rs
      .AddNew
        ![a] = 1
        ![b] = 1
        ![c] = 1
      .Update
    End With

    rs.Clone

    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    Me.FirstField.ControlSource = rs.Fields(0).Name 'outputs #Error in FirstField
End Sub
```

Help is much appreciated!

---

### What I'm trying to do

I have a database which represent used parking spaces in a parking lot. A,B,C are position coordinates each of these have a validation rule set so they cannot exceed their limits. Now I want to display all available parking spaces.
So I figured I'd create a "fake" database with all parking spaces and then do a query-thing where I only display entires from the fake database where the position is not in the "used parking space" database.

Creating a database with only the positions seemed silly to me and populating the "used parking space" database with all parking spaces and then adding a used boolean field also seemed like a bad idea.

I welcome input on how I could solve this in a better way.

*Thank you for you time.*

Comment: I do not see why a list of possible parking places is a bad idea.

Comment: A list is fine, that's sort of what I'm trying to make using the recordset as an arraylist. But a database for just this purpose would be hard to maintain, imagine if there was 20k parking spaces.

Comment: I do not see the problem 20K records is not very many and 20K disconnected recordset is not a good idea. You are fighting uphill with this idea in MS Access. You would really need to build a table rather than use a disconnected recordset and then you would have to deal with bloat.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'll do some redesigning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I see you intend to redesign, which seems like a good idea to me.  Despite that, if you want to experiment further with an ADO disconnected recordset for a form, include `.LockType` before `.Open`.

```
rs.LockType = adLockPessimistic
rs.Open
```

With that change, and discarding the `rs.Clone` line, your `Form_Load` code works on my test form.

See this article from *Database Journal* for more details on this subject: [Create In-Memory ADO Recordsets](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm).