# ADO inserts causes #error in previous records on continuous forms vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb, ms-access-forms

I have a Ms Access application frontend which uses ADO to access a SQL Server 14 Database.
There is a continuous form that is bounded with an ADODB recordset.

I have a function for the connection string

```
Function getConnectionString() As ADODB.Connection

    Set getConnectionString = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    ' Set Connection String here!
    getConnectionString.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=localhost;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=DBNAME;Encrypt=Yes;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;"
    getConnectionString.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    getConnectionString.Mode = adModeReadWrite

End Function
```

The Cursor set up

```vb
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic`
```

I have a function that binds the recordset to the form. If the user is about to enter a new record, this happens:

Form1

```
**ROWIDVENDOR**           **TICKET**
3           LAFARGE          123654789
4           HALTON           852369741
5           DUFFERIN         852741639
6           MILTON
```

*User is about to enter data*

Form1

```
**ROWIDVENDOR**           **TICKET**
3           LAFARGE          123654789
4           HALTON           852369741
6           #ERROR           #ERROR
6           MILTON           123
```

Does anyone know how to handle that issue or has a workaround?

Comment: That looks like a DAO connection string, not an ADODB one. Also, this is far from a [mre]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44030063/11683? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9703912/11683?

Comment: @ErikA - This is an ADODB connectionstring.

Comment: @GSerg - Thanks, but I tried this solution to close the recordset or the connection, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @sedioben It isn't a valid one... Please provide your full code. ADODB strings don't start with `ODBC;`, that's a DAO thing, and you shouldn't specify a DSN and then specify driver as well as driver is already specified in the DSN. It's all sorts of weird.

Comment: @ErikA - Thanks for your comment. I corrected it and edited the post.However, I still have the same problem. Do you have an idea to solve it ?

Comment: Not really, only that I've got dubious experience with the MSDASQL provider and I'd try a SQL server OLEDB provider instead. I've cast a reopen vote since now you actually have code that could work